# (Kivy) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error, kivy, kivy-language

I'm watching a tutorial, by Sentdex, on Kivy. An error appeared when i ran the code. It won't let me make a map and says the colon is invalid syntax.

```
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require("1.9.1")
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return  FloatLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

and

```
# file name: tutorialApp
# Kivy 1.9.1

<Button>:
    font_size: 40
    color: 0,1,0,1
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.2


<FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "Kivy"
        pos_hint: ('x' : 0, 'top' : 1)


    Button:
        text: "Tutorials"
        pos_hint: ("right" : 1, 'top' : 1)
```

the error showed

```
   File "<string>", line 1
 ('x' : 0, 'top' : 1)
      ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yes, that's invalid syntax. You can't have a colon inside a tuple. Did you perhaps mean to define a dictionary? Those use `{` and `}`.

Comment: That worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, I think, but I'm not sure, you need to make a class in Python for the `floatlayout` and the `button`:

```
class FloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

And don't forget if you do it, to import FloatLayout. And for the error, it is `pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'top' : 1}` and same for the other, and not `pos_hint: ('x'...)`

Comment: Can I suggest you format the code you are trying to share to make it more readable?

Comment: Thanks, I'm on smartphone and I can't make code area.